How to implement Cloud Convert API in Node.js
I am trying to implement the Cloud Convert API into my simple website which is a collection of tools that let you do a number of operations on different types of documents. One of them is conversion of a file into some other format.
So I was trying to make that, starting with PDF to DOCX format. I tried searching for a number of things. Then stumbled upon the Cloud Convert API.
Now I can't get it to work. Can Someone help or guide me with it?
my app.js is:
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const fs = require('fs');
const CloudConvert = require('cloudconvert');

const app = express();
const upload = multer({ dest: './uploads' });
const API_KEY = 'my_key'; 
const cloudConvert = new CloudConvert({ apiKey: API_KEY });

app.post('/upload', upload.single('pdfFile'), async (req, res) => {
    try {
        if (!req.file) {
            return res.status(400).send('No file uploaded.');
        }

        const pdfPath = req.file.path;
        const job = await cloudConvert.jobs.create({
            tasks: {
                'import-my-file': {
                    operation: 'import/upload',
                    file: fs.createReadStream(pdfPath)
                },
                'convert-my-file': {
                    operation: 'convert',
                    input: 'import-my-file',
                    output_format: 'docx'
                },
                'export-my-file': {
                    operation: 'export/url',
                    input: 'convert-my-file'
                }
            }
        });

        const finishedJob = await cloudConvert.jobs.wait(job.id);
        if (finishedJob.status === 'error') {
            console.error('Conversion failed:', finishedJob.message);
            return res.status(500).send('Conversion failed. Please try again later.');
        }

        const exportTask = finishedJob.tasks.filter(task => task.name === 'export-my-file')[0];
        const downloadUrl = exportTask.result.files[0].url;
        res.status(200).json({ downloadUrl });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error during conversion:', error.message);
        res.status(500).send('Conversion failed. Please try again later.');
    }
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});


But it just gives me "cannot GET" error. I don't know what that means.
